# svjour3: Appendix table numbers increment +2 using table and tabularx

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltablex, xltabular

I know that my question below may be similar like this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377392/table-numbers-not-incrementing-properly), nevertheless I kindly ask you for your patience, as I am using some different tabular environments.

The appendix of my document based on the Springer class `svjour3` is full of tables, which need proper caption, label and floating. After some experiments with different column types and environments, I came  to the point that the setup in MWE below is working well for the table style. However, I face the issue of wrong increment in table numbering - every table seems to consume 2 counting steps instead of one.

What is going wrong here and how can the table definition be improved?
Thank you in advance!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} 
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}  
\smartqed  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{footnote} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{L{#1}}
\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Normal section}
This is a standard main text.

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\section{Appendix Section 1}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Appendix Table 1}
    \label{tab:AppTable1}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L{2.5cm}|X@{}} 
        \toprule
            \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} \\\midrule
            a & b \\
            \midrule
            c & d \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Appendix Table 2}
    \label{tab:AppTable2}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L{2.5cm}|X@{}} 
        \toprule
            \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} \\\midrule
            a & b \\
            \midrule
            c & d \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue you observe is unrelated to the documentclass you use but caused by the `ltablex` package. For a suggestion on how to get rid of this issue, you might want to take a look at: tex.stackexchange.com/a/375104/134144. Personally, I'd suggest replacing the `ltablex` package with `xltabular`, while also replacing all `tabularx` envrironments that are supposed to stretch across multiple pages with the `xltabular` environment.

Comment: Also keep in mind that horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package were designed to be used without vertical lines, hence the small gaps around all the intersections, that you can see in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments were helpful and pointed to the right direction. Replacing `ltablex` package  with the `xltabular` package corrects the issue observed in labelling.